# Joomla com_extplorer keep reloading page

Tags: joomla, components, aruba

I'm used to install extplorer in every joomla project, always everthing going well.
This time at the extplorer launch time its keep loading the web page in loop mode( tried to change permissions in administrator/components , triade to let Aruba install joomla) nothing worked.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Don't know what you are saying with `triade to let Aruba install joomla`?  What web page is looping?  The main home page? We need more details.

Comment: *tried T9 works bad :) anyway Yes the joomla administrator home page

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Admintools extension installed and a custom .htaccess file?

If yes, open AdminTools and htaccess maker.
Under Server Protection>Exceptions>Allow direct access to these files

Add the following line:

> administrator/components/com_extplorer/fetchscript.php

to the list of allowed files and regenerate your .htaccess.